Cannot type/select Android application id when running "flutterfire configure"
For some reason, when configuring Firebase with a Flutter project by running flutterfire configure, I always get to this step where it prompts me to enter/select the Android application id but doesn't let me type nor select anything, if I just hit enter then it uses an empty application name and errors out.
The error only happens for android, every other platform (web, ios, windows, macos) goes through smoothly and never asks me to provide the application Id like android does.
(It doesn't let me type nor select, every input is ignored except Ctrl+C and Enter)

(It then proceeded with an empty Application Id and then complained about it)

